# variable contraints in OPL/CPLEX

Tags: variables, constraints, cplex, opl

i want to implement a variable constraint in OPL.

forall(k in products, t in periods, z in t..periods)

z is suppose to model the current and all future periods after t.
The model says its not possible to implement variable constraints.
How can i express the constraint instead?

Is this a way out?
forall(k in Produkte, t in Perioden, z in Perioden: z>=t)

Comment: Have you tried it? Show us what you have tried and the error messages that you got, that gives us more information to help you.

Comment: I have for example the following code. The problem is the variabe index length. k is the index for products and i for stores. availableproducts is a set of products assigned to each store. the constraint should ensure that people can just buy the amount of product k in store i (=x[i,k]), that is first available in the store and on inventory: forall(i in Stores, k in AvailableProducts[i])
     Constraint: //Inventory flow
      x[i,k]<=Amount[k]*q[i,AvailableProducts[k]];